# Finding unit vectors the form an angle with another vector

Tags: vectors

Question:

Find two unit vectors in 2-space that make an angle of $45°$ with $4i + 3j$.

I tried letting the other vector, v = ai +bj.

Then I used the dot product trying to obtain and and b,

$(4i+3j).(ai+bj)=5||v||cos45$

$(4a + 3b) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}||v||\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$(16a^2 + 9b^2) = \frac{25}{{2}}(a^2+b^2)$

Once I get here, I'm unsure how to progress. I end up with a multi-variable expression I'm not too sure how to solve.

Comment: $(4a + 3b)^2 = 16 a^2 + 9b^2$?  This is the freshman's dream.  How do you multiply binomials?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for two *unit* vectors, so $\|v\|=1$.

Also, I don't see a connection between the equation $$(4i+3j).(ai+bj)=5||v||cos45$$

and

$$(4a + 3b) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}||v||\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Can you explain how one follows from the other? I need to understand your thinking before I can direct it to the answer.

Comment: I edited my question, I had one too many ||v||'s!

Answer (score 0):

Unit vectors have a magnitude of 1, that is why they are called unit. You are looking at two solutions, as the vector you are looking for can be "on both sides" of the given vector.

The system of equations you should be solving is:

`4a + 3b = 5/sqrt(2)`

`a^2 + b^2 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = (4, 3) = 5 (\cos \phi, \sin \phi) $ where $\phi = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{3}{4} $

The unit vectors which are $45^\circ = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ from vector $a$ are

$ v_1 = (\cos(\phi + \dfrac{\pi}{4}), \sin(\phi + \dfrac{\pi}{4})) $

and

$v_2 =  (\cos(\phi - \dfrac{\pi}{4}), \sin(\phi - \dfrac{\pi}{4}) )$

Now, we note that $\cos \phi = \dfrac{4}{5} $ and $\sin \phi = \dfrac{3}{5} $

Hence,

$\cos(\phi + \dfrac{\pi}{4}) = \dfrac{1}{5\sqrt{2}} $

$\sin(\phi + \dfrac{\pi}{4}) = \dfrac{7}{5 \sqrt{2}} $

which makes $v_1 = \dfrac{1}{5\sqrt{2}} ( 1, 7) $

Using a similar argument

$ v_2 = \dfrac{1}{5\sqrt{2}} ( 7, -1 ) $

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers are your friend.

We can map from the real plane to the complex plane mapping the the $\mathbb i$ vector to the real unit and the $\mathbb j$ vector to the imaginary unit.

$4\mathbf i + 3\mathbf j \to 4+3i$

Next we multiply by an imaginary number that makes a 45 degree angle with the real line.  $1+i$ will do.  So would $1-i.$

$(1 + i)(4+3i) = 1 + 7i$

And reverse the map

$\mathbf i + 7\mathbf j$

You have been asked to find the unit vector so just normalize this.

But you don't like complex numbers.... From your work.

$(4a + 3b) = \frac {5}{\sqrt 2} (a^2  + b^2)\\
\sqrt 2 (4a + 3b) = 5 (a^2  + b^2)\\
2 (16a^2 +24ab+ 9b^2) = 25a^2  + 25 b^2\\
32a^2 - 25a^2 + 48ab + 9b^2 - 25b^2 = 0\\
7a^2 + 48ab -7b^2 = 0$

Now factor this (or jam it through the binomial theorem)

$(7a - b)(a+7b) = 0$